# Facebook group management using API

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

we have internal corporate group in Facebook. We need to manage group members using API. Unfortunately I didn't find any way to join or remove user from Facebook group. So, is there any way to remove users from Facebook group using API?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but this is currently not possible using the Groups object in the Graph API.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the new v2.1 API release?
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/group/members/

Should help to find what you are looking for, you cannot add members directly - but you can ofcourse invite them to join and deleting is in API's control if you have admin permission